# pytest breaks with pip install

Tags: python, pip, pytest

I'm working in a repo that has tests and some test helper libraries in a directory named `test` (https://github.com/covid-projections/covid-data-model/tree/main/test).  Mysteriously `pip install dash` seems to break our tests. I'm using python 3.7.9 in pyenv on a debian laptop.  I reproduced the problem with a pretty simple example:

Activate a fresh pyenv virtualenv and install the latest pytest with `pip install git+https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest`. Create an empty `./test/__init__.py` and the following two files:

```
$ cat ./test/real_test.py
from test import test_helpers

def test_one():
  assert "foobar" == test_helpers.SOME_CONSTANT
$ cat ./test/test_helpers.py
SOME_CONSTANT = "foo"
```

Running test/real_test.py does the expected, failing a test. Now `pip install dash==1.19.0` and the test fails to run with

```
_____________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test/real_test.py _____________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/thecap/tmp/nomodule/test/real_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.real_test'
```

Running `pytest --import-mode=importlib test/real_test.py` (found in the comments of https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/7408) gives me a little hint that it isn't including the cwd in the path used to search for libraries because it is looking at a `test` in the pyenv, not in the cwd.

```
ImportError while importing test module '/home/thecap/tmp/nomodule/test/real_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test/real_test.py:1: in <module>
    from test import test_helpers
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'test_helpers' from 'test' (/home/thecap/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/test/__init__.py)
```

Mysteriously to me after running `pip uninstall dash` the test runs as expected with `pytest test/real_test.py` but is still broken with `pytest --import-mode=importlib test/real_test.py`.

I suspect moving our tests from `test/` to `tests/` will fix this but I'd like to understand why installing dash breaks things and if our current setup is a problem, help other people avoid it.

(I posted this at https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/discussions/8270 too and hoping for more response on stack overflow.)

Comment: This is an interesting question, somehow the rootdir is not in `sys.path` when `dash` is installed. Running without the plugin active works: `pytest test/real_test.py -p no:dash`, also explicitly adding the rootdir to `sys.path` works: `python -m pytest test/real_test.py` or `PYTHONPATH=. pytest test/real_test.py`. I still don't see why installing `dash` breaks it, though.

Comment: I guess the issue with `dash` is that it uses code from `futures` which imports `test` when installing aliases, so your local package can't be imported later when `pytest` starts tests collection (`pytest` prepends the project root dir to `sys.path` and invokes `import test`, but `sys.modules` already contains `test` from the stdlib, so it has no effect. This is why prepending root dir to `sys.path` early enough works, but then the aliasing `futures` do will be wrong, I suppose).

Comment: Short answer - don't create packages or modules that are name-shadowing the standard library, this will always break something sooner or later :-)

Comment: Although I'd also say this isn't your fault at all - [`test` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html) clearly state that it _is meant for internal use by Python only._ I'm rather surprised the stdlib uses it outside of the internal regression test run. As a workaround, I can suggest creating a `conftest.py` in the project root dir with the contents `import sys; sys.modules.pop("test", None)` - this should resolve the import issue.

Comment: Thank you very much @hoefling! I tested the conftest.py work-around and we're going to rename test to tests. I'll also update the github discussion and try to file a bug with the stdlib.

Comment: I consider this answered. How do you want to mark the stack overflow question as such?

Comment: Glad I could help! I've added an answer (which mostly just restates the comments) which you can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that your local `test` package shadows the [`test`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html) module from the standard library. In general, name shadowing any stdlib modules is a bad practice and should be avoided; however, since

> The `test` package is meant for internal use by Python only. It is documented for the benefit of the core developers of Python. Any use of this package outside of Python’s standard library is discouraged as code mentioned here can change or be removed without notice between releases of Python.

and

> The `test` package contains all regression tests for Python as well as the modules `test.support` and `test.regrtest`. `test.support` is used to enhance your tests while `test.regrtest` drives the testing suite.

one would imply that `test` isn't used outside of the regression test run. This isn't true for `future`, though - [it's importing `test.support` when installing aliases](https://python-future.org/standard_library_imports.html#aliased-imports), causing stdlib's `test` to be present in `sys.modules` before `pytest` starts test collection. You installed `futures` along with `dash`, since [it's a direct dependency](https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/8edc3399bd7ded47f6546008f0e0696a734d98d3/requires-install.txt#L8). Now when you start a `pytest` run, it loads the `dash` plugin which imports `future` which imports `test` and afterwards, when trying to collect your local `test` package, `pytest` fails on import since another `test` is already imported!

#### Solution

I would suggest to rename the local `test` package into e.g. `tests`. This will stop the name shadowing of the stdlib module.

If you can't rename the test package, one can imagine several workarounds to circumvent the import of stdlib's `test`:

#### Clean up the import

Create a file `conftest.py` in your project root dir (not in the `test` dir, or it won't work) with the following contents:

```
import sys

sys.modules.pop("test", None)
```

This will "unimport" stdlib's `test`, making your local `test` package importable on test collection.

#### Alter `sys.path` to make local `test` package selectable before stdlib ones

Just run `python -m pytest ...` or `PYTHONPATH=. pytest ...` to ensure the root dir of your project is inserted before the site in `sys.path`, so `import test` will always end in importing your local package.

Comment: Case closed! Thank you hoefling!